# is tomcat starting?

Tags: tomcat, centos

by running command $ ./startup.sh I am getting

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-7.0.37
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-7.0.37
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

and then the control is returned to shell again, how can I found that tomcat started successfully or have thrown some error?

Comment: See the log message by using this `tail -f catalina.out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the log files in `log` to see if an error was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any error, is running, to test open your browser and go to:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

8080 is the default tomcat port, if you have changed it in the configuration files change the URL. You should see the tomcat welcome page.

You can test if it's running in the shell too:

```
ps aux | grep tomcat
```

You can see the logs with (from the tomcat directory):

```
cat logs/catalina.out
```

Comment: You can check for the `tomcat`process or see the logs as I wrote in the answer